# how to use a binary tree to get partial sumation of a stack in log(n) time complexity

Tags: java, sum, time-complexity, binary-tree

I am almost done with a custom data structure but I'm stuck on this last feature since I have little to no experience working with trees. I need to add a function that can get the sum of the first k elements in the stack. for example, in the stack [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the sum of the first 3 elements is 5+4+3 = 12. it all needs to be in log(n) time complexity or as close as possible. This should be accomplished by creating a binary tree whose leaves are the elements in the stack and the parents are the sum of their 2 children. here is an example of what the tree should look like

```
                           38
                         /    \
                       21     17
                      /  \   /  \
                     13   8 10   7
```

I need to be able to set an element to a new value and values can only be added or removed from the front since the "main" data is being stored in a stack.

I have an implementation of this using a regular arrayList but its runtime is O(n) and not the desired O(log(n))

```
public long ksum(int k) {
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<k && i<ds.size(); i++)
      sum += ds.get(ds.size() - 1 - i);
    return sum;
  }
```

here is the whole code of what I have so far. There will be changes to be made in  the functions like push, pop and set to update the data structure as well as the ksum function itself

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class UltraFast implements UltraStack {
    protected Stack<Integer> stack;
    protected PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap;

    public UltraFast() {
        stack = new Stack<>();
        maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a));
    }

    public void push(int x) {
        stack.push(x);
        maxHeap.offer(x);

    }

    public Integer pop() {
      if (stack.isEmpty()) {
          return null;
      }
      int top = stack.pop();
      maxHeap.remove(top);


      return top;
  }
  

    public Integer set(int i, int x) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= stack.size())
            return null;

        int oldValue = stack.get(i);
        stack.set(i, x);

        maxHeap.remove(oldValue);
        maxHeap.offer(x);

        return oldValue;
    }

    public long ksum(int k) {
      //code here
      return null;
  }
  
  

    public Integer get(int i) {
      if (i < 0 || i >= stack.size())
        return null;
        return stack.get(i);
    }

    public Integer max() {
      if (maxHeap.isEmpty()) {
         return null;
      }
      return maxHeap.peek();
    }

    public int size() {
        return stack.size();
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return stack.iterator();
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Please define exactly what "first k elements" means.

Comment: i have updated the post to add this example: in the stack [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the sum of the first 3 elements is 5+4+3 = 12

Comment: You can return the sum of the first k elements in constant time and without a tree. I don't understand the question. btw, why are 5,4 and 3 the "first elements" of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? Did you mean the "last k elements"? Or are you iterating last to first?

Comment: I see no attempt in your code to create the binary tree. You *do* create a heap, but that is a different structure from what you described (it doesn't store sums as internal nodes). What is holding you back to start implementing that tree?

Comment: How should that tree look like for your example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],?

Comment: i have never really worked with binary trees before so im not sure where to start. do i need to make a whole new class file or can i implement it directly into the existing ultrafast class i have. as for " why are 5,4 and 3 the "first elements" of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?", the actual data itself is being stored in a stack so the first in this case is the top of the stack. In the tree example i gave, 13 8 10 and 7 are the elements of the stack and the parents are all their sum.